# Linked List In Data Structures

Tags: c, linked-list

Suppose `temp` is a pointer to structure `node`. `temp->next` is `NULL`. So what will be the value of `temp->next->next`?

In short what is the value of `NULL->next`? Is it compiler dependent because I have seen different result in ubuntu and code blocks(windows)?

What will be the output of the program below?

```
 struct node
 {
  int data;
   struct node *next;
 };

 main()
 {
   struct node *temp,*p;
   int c=0;
   temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp->data=50;
   temp->next=NULL;
   p=temp;
   if(p->next->next==NULL)//will it enter the if loop?
      c++;
   printf("%d",c);
  }
```

Comment: Should throw a segfault while evaluating the IF condition.

Comment: Not necessarily. Especially in Windows there is no segfaults... It's an undefined behaviour. It can blow up the Moon, for example, so please don't do this. We still need it.

Comment: [Please do not cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's yet another 'I know it's UB but I still want SO contributors to waste time on it'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL->next must give you a segfault.

You may want to have something like :

```
if(p->next != NULL && p->next->next==NULL)
```

or

```
if(p->next == NULL || p->next->next==NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `temp->next` is NULL, dereferencing it to get `temp->next->next` is [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).  A crash is likely, but other things could happen.  In principle, *anything* could happen.

Don't dereference null pointers.